# Customizing the node create form using a template file

Tags: theming, nodes

I have created a template file for my content type, but I don't know how to get form design in that page.

My content type name is wallpaper, and I created the *page--node--add--wallpaper.tpl.php* template file. How do I access the node title, or the node body, in the template file?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to design the form then use `hook_form_alter` you will get form `array`. If you want to design the node page then user `node--content_type.tpl.php`.

Comment: I agree: I would never use a template file to alter the way a form is shown. `hook_form_alter()` can be implemented from a theme too, even if it is generally implemented by a module.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom module

First, alter the original form

```
function YOURMODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_wallpaper_form') {
    $form['#theme'] = 'your_theme_name';
  }
}

function YOURMODULENAME_theme() {
  return array(
    'your_theme_name' => array(
      'variables' => array('form' => NULL),
      'template' => 'template_file_name',
    ),
  );
}
```

In the template_file_name.tpl.php put fields :

```
print drupal_render($form['field_name']);

//Drupal needs to render form_id, form token etc as well so also put this:
print drupal_render_children($form);
```

Answer (score -1):

[`node.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7) is the base node template.

If you look at the source code you can find all variables to render values in that `.tpl` file.

Available variables:

- **$title**: the (sanitized) title of the node.
- **$content**: An array of node items. Use render($content) to print them all,
  or print a subset such as render($content['field_example']). Use
  hide($content['field_example']) to temporarily suppress the printing of a
  given element.
- **$user_picture**: The node author's picture from user-picture.tpl.php.
- **$date**: Formatted creation date. Preprocess functions can reformat it by
  calling format_date() with the desired parameters on the $created variable.
- **$name**: Themed username of node author output from theme_username().
- **$node_url**: Direct URL of the current node.
- **$display_submitted**: Whether submission information should be displayed.
- **$submitted**: Submission information created from $name and $date during
  template_preprocess_node().
- **$classes**: String of classes that can be used to style contextually through
  CSS. It can be manipulated through the variable $classes_array from
  preprocess functions. The default values can be one or more of the
  following:

  - **node**: The current template type; for example, "theming hook".
  - **node-[type]**: The current node type. For example, if the node is a
    "Blog entry" it would result in "node-blog". Note that the machine
    name will often be in a short form of the human readable label.
  - **node-teaser**: Nodes in teaser form.
  - **node-preview**: Nodes in preview mode.

  The following are controlled through the node publishing options.

  - **node-promoted**: Nodes promoted to the front page.
  - **node-sticky**: Nodes ordered above other non-sticky nodes in teaser
    listings.
  - **node-unpublished**: Unpublished nodes visible only to administrators.
- **$title_prefix (array)**: An array containing additional output populated by
  modules, intended to be displayed in front of the main title tag that
  appears in the template.
- **$title_suffix (array)**: An array containing additional output populated by
  modules, intended to be displayed after the main title tag that appears in
  the template.

Other variables:

- **$node**: Full node object. Contains data that may not be safe.
- **$type**: Node type; for example, story, page, blog, etc.
- **$comment_count**: Number of comments attached to the node.
- **$uid**: User ID of the node author.
- **$created**: Time the node was published formatted in Unix timestamp.
- **$classes_array**: Array of html class attribute values. It is flattened
  into a string within the variable $classes.
- **$zebra**: Outputs either "even" or "odd". Useful for zebra striping in
  teaser listings.
- **$id**: Position of the node. Increments each time it's output.